# Javascript Pausing loop waiting on event

Tags: javascript, for-loop

i am using:

```
for(i = 0; i < numPages; i++)
{
returnViewONE.setPage(array[i]);
alert("page "+array[i]+" set");
returnViewONE.savePage(sFolderPath+i+"file.tiff");
alert(sFolderPath+i+"file.tiff Saved");
}
```

but i am finding without the alerts this is failling to save the 2nd 3rd....pages, is there a way of pausing a loop waiting for an event.
we have an event 6 which is fired when a page is saved.

such as

```
for(i = 0; i < numPages; i++)
{
returnViewONE.setPage(array[i]);
alert("page "+array[i]+" set");
returnViewONE.savePage(sFolderPath+i+"file.tiff");
alert(sFolderPath+i+"file.tiff Saved");
when (id == 6) then loop untill i++
}
```

Comment: Should we magically guess what's in `setPage` and `savePage` methods?

Comment: *"..we have an event 6 which is fired when a page is saved..."* You have an event called "6"? Are you a *really* die-hard *The Prisoner* fan?

Comment: @raina77ow: I figure `returnViewONE` is the ViewONE TIFF viewer from Daeja.

Comment: Might it be easier to instead of using a for loop before you have the prerequisites, to then start it after you have id == 6. can you add conditional logic to start the loop on id == 6?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can pause a loop, but maybe you could keep looping and checking your condition without doing anything until the condition is met. What if you used a while loop, and didn't increment your counter until the condition you're waiting for is met?

```
i = 0;
lastIteration = -1;
while(i < numPages) {
  if(i > lastIteration) {
    returnViewONE.setPage(array[i]);
    returnViewONE.savePage(sFolderPath+i+"file.tiff");
  }

  lastIteration = i;

  if(/*savePage has completed*/) {
   i++;
  }
}
```

This would loop forever if savePage never completed, so you'd have to have some kind of safety mechanism in there as well.